# android tab to show vertically at the left hand side of screen in landscape view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

I know that it is possible to place the tabs at the top or bottom view in portrait mode. However when i moved the orientation to the landscape view, the tabs will be in a row horizontally at the top.

I saw that it is possible when i opened up the `Calendar` application in my android phone, because the tabs are vertical in horizontal view, at the left hand side too.

Is there any way to change it to appear at the left hand side `vertically` on the screen?
is it possible to change it through doing different views in layout-port and layout-land, or change manifest.xml or any other possible way through coding

thanks for the help in advance. this problem has been quite hard to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experiments, I found out that there's very little customisation available that you can do with Tabs' position.
This, as an answer, I would say, till now we can't position tabs on the left or right.
I may be wrong, but this is what I feel.

However, you're always free to write your own tab implementation and use it.

Comment: ok thanks alot sheikh! :D i tried many ways and still unable to do so.

Comment: That is what. I don't think that it provides us with a way to do that. However, you could develop something on your own to implement such functionality. If you need the concepts, I surely can help.

Answer (score 2):

I think for creating a layout with Tabs on the left hand side, you can get related information on this link: [Left Side Tab Widget](http://code.google.com/p/themissingtabwidget/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but you can make it better by including a summary or relevant portions of the pages you're linking to. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.